# When do you get bonus flags?

Tags: support, flags

> When you start out you are alloted 10 flags per-day. This number may increase to up to 100 flags per-day:
>
> - You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation.
> - You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly.

The Privileges page is very specific with regards to everything else, but it doesn't quantify when the additional bonus flags are earned. For instance, is it one flag for every 10 helpful flags? One every hundred? Is it reset daily or an overall tally?